# su using own password instead of root password?

Tags: sudo, centos6

I'm editing using `visudo` and looking at the following line:

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

And when I add a user to the `wheel` group, they are able to `su` however they must put in the root password to do so.

Sometime in the past I remember having access to a machine and when I would `su` it would require my own password instead of the root password. How do I setup `visudo` to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably

```
sudo -i
```

`su` has nothing to do with the `sudoers` (`visudo`) file.

Answer (score 3):

If you run `sudo su` you can do this.

Comment: Ah yes I remember that was how it was done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this is not set in /etc/sudoers when you edit it with the visudo command

> rootpw
>
> ```
> If set, sudo will prompt for the root password instead of the
> ```
>
> password of the invoking user. This flag is off by default.

From:
http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html